# calling another view of an UIViewController doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

im trying to load another nib of a UIViewController after expected time. Everything does work but wenn i load the UIViewController i get a exception when it is called. I'm doing it that way:

```
UIViewController *overView = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"overView2" bundle:nil];

[super presentViewController:overView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

i also tried to insert [NSBundle mainBundle] instead of "nil" but the exception still occures. 
When i push the UIViewController in following was, no exception occures but after the first view is removed nothing happends:

```
[self.parentViewController addChildViewController:overView];
```

i were searching long time but couldn't find a solution...

---

SOLUTION

I just found the mistake.

I imported the H-File of the UIViewController in the M-File where i wanted to load the new View.Than i created a new object and passed it through.

```
overView2 *overView = [[overView2 alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:overView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

sorry, I'm new to objectiv-c...maybe will help some other beginners too :P

Answer (score 0):

A standard implementation of presenting a view controller is:

```
[self presentViewController:overView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Unless I'm missing something.  Is there any more information that you can give?

Comment: so it normally should work. Don't know what could help you furthermore. I created another UIViewController which displayes a black background with a label. The label is connected to the .h-file of the UIViewController i want to load. Don't think that it is the problem why it doesn't work.